# Checking if a set is algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Given a subset of $\mathbb C^n,$ is there some way to check if it is the zero set of a collection of polynomials of degree $\le d?$ Certainly when $d=1$ this is easy, and for larger $d$ there are many necessary conditions - but is any of them sufficient?

Comment: What information are you given about the subset? That is, in what form is the subset presented to you?

Comment: Just as a collection of points with no structure given. What I'd really like is some kind of "closure" condition under some operations. For example, in the linear case if a set is closed under scalar multipication and vector addition it is the zero set of linear functions. The addition condition can be rephrased (weirdly) as follows: "If three corners of a parallelogram are in the set then the fourth corner is as well". This follows from the second (discrete) derivative of a linear function vanishing. Can higher dimensional parallelopipeds replace parallelograms for higher degree polynomials?

Comment: If the subset is infinite, then how is the collection of points specified? For example, is it given by a system of equations of some form that might not be obviously algebraic? Is it given by a list of properties that characterize it but don't take the form of equations at all? Some other method?

Comment: I don't have a specific set in mind, I was asking about a general algorithm. Suppose we can ask about any point we want if it is in the set or not. Is there anything more clever we can do than check all the candidate polynomials?

Comment: To specify an algorithm, we have to know something about the format of the inputs to the algorithm. If all we have is a black box that can answer "is this point in the set, yes/no?" for any given point, then we don't have enough information, because a finite algorithm can only ask about a finite number of points in this way. (That's not even enough to determine whether a set is finite or infinite.)

Answer (score 0):

So here is one way to check: Let $I(X)\subset \mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be the ideal of polynomials vanishing on $X$ and let $V(I(X))\subset \mathbb C^n$ be the collection of common zeros of the polynomials in $I(X).$ Then $X$ is an algebraic set if and only if $V(I(X)) = X.$ Then to find the degree we have to find generators for $I(X)$ of minimal degrees. What bothers me about this criterion is that we have to know what the global polynomial functions are and check if they vanish on $X.$ On the other hand, to test if $X$ is a subspace we just have to check that it's closed under scalars and addition which are conditions on the **points** of $X$ not involving the global polynomials. I'm wondering if there is a similar condition on the points of $X$ that we can check for higher degrees?